# Inno Setup - Using {app} in Preprocessor

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I want ISPP to check if a file/folder exists in {app} during `InitializeUninstall`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That does not make sense. The preprocessor is run when you build the setup. Not when installing/uninstalling.

---

But of course you can use the constants in the Pascal Script, using the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant). To check a file existence, use the [`FileExists` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists).

```pascal
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.ini')) then
  begin
    Log('File exists.');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('File does not exist.');
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

---

For directories, use the [`DirExists` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_direxists).

Comment: Yeah, well, the thing is, I need the check to work in the `Messages` section. Updating question.

Comment: The updated question is here: [Change Inno Setup messages from Pascal code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35887348/850848).